# including external headers finding out compiler options

Tags: c++, c, compilation, header-files

Say I find a very nice open source library in the internet and now I want to use it for my own project.

I download it, possibly compile it and get the header files & the static/dynamic library.

So I start writing my own source files and of course when I want to use functionality from this external library I include the right headers of it into my source files.

Now I compile my source file, make sure the include paths and linker options for this external library are set correctly.

And I get heaps of errors, all coming from the external headers.
Turns out they require some compiler flags.

**How do I find out the minimal compiler flags that I have to set (to be able to compile headers from an external library)?**

What I've thought about it so far:

1. Look them up in the building script of the source (can be quite hard, since there are many places where they can be defined and they may not be the minimal flags, since they may be required for all headers together, but not for specific ones I use)
2. Google every error message and hopefully that'll give the answer (can be hard with a lot of error messages and google might not know the answer, or I might not know the right keywords to find the answer)
3. Maybe somehow 'include' the build script of the external library into my own project (could be very hard, since I might want to use a different build system and I'd probably have to fully understand the build system myself, which could be hard for bigger libraries)

Comment: this looks like it usually is a build system problem? Why do you include the other sourcecode into your project instead of using the other projects buildsystem? I know buildsystems are a pain in the ass, but thats what they were made for.

Comment: I only include the headers of the other project. I don't know how I'm supposed to use the c/++ definitions of the other project without the headers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any well behaved open source library ships with instructions on how to use their development files. On GNU/Linux systems, it's usual to have [pkg-config](http://pkg-config.freedesktop.org) files (*.pc) installed together to development headers and libraries, in which case `pkg-config --cflags library-name` will tell about required compilation options.

Where `pkg-config` can be used, it's just a matter of telling the build-system which components you'd like to import. E.g. on autotools.

```
PKG_CHECK_MODULES([DEPS], [libname])
```

And then make use of `DEPS_CFLAGS` and `DEPS_LIBS` variables on .am files.

E.g. on a shell command-line:

```
$ gcc $(pkg-config --cflags libname) -c main.c
$ gcc $(pkg-config --libs libname) main.o -o test.exe
```

Anyway, it'd be more productive if you could post specific info about the library used and which are the errors being generated.

Comment: oh wow, I didn't even know about pkg-config, but that sounds like a great solution. Is pkg-config very popular amongst the more popular open source projects?
You don't happen to have any advice on a strategy someone could use in case there isn't good documentation about required compiler flags for header files?

Comment: yes, `pkg-config` can be considered a *de facto standard* among FOSS projects.
I'm not sure I understood the question about the strategy, but usually there is a mechanism in the build system to declare the *.pc files or you can just substitute the output of `pkg-config --cflags libname` on a command-line.

Answer (score 0):

For a header this is very rare to have errors about flags of the compiler or it is very easy to solve it in that header( for example using #ifdef..#endif or try to re-write a portion of code using a more wel known pattern ).

but more possible error is something like this: You include header directly but that header is dependent on some other header( possibly from system or from the same library ) and you forget to include them before main include file.( actually this is common file between programmers that forget to make their headers standalone, simply they forget to include all required headers of their file in correct order in the main include file ).

So in order to test for this criteria look in the source code of the library( that you say it is compiled correctly ). see what included before main include file and you may find that your include file is dependent in include files that included before it.

For example in both MSVC and GCC you can use precompiled headers and any include in the precompiled headers will be included automatically in all source files that include it, so if you forget to add something in one of your public headers and include it in your precompiled header your code will be compiled correctly but if someone include your public header will get an error.

or if you define something in `private_header_1.h` and use it in your public header and then in your source file( for example `impl.cpp` you say:
    #include "private_header_1.h"
    #include "public_header.h"
again your code will be compiled correctly but including `public_header.h` in another code will raise an error

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid having to use #ifdef...#endif and rewriting portions of code.
I think you got a good point with the order of header inclusion, I guess things can go wrong there too.
However I'm really more interested in resolving problems concerning compiler flags.
And I'm a bit unsure about precompiled headers: how they work, whether they're a good choice...

Comment: @deaf7 precompiled headers are so lovely, they can decrease build time significantly. You will include stable headers( like system headers or standard C++ headers ) in pch and then compiler will compile them only once not in every C++ unit that it compile and it work very well in both MSVC and GCC. but here I do not tell to use #ifdef..#endif or pch, instead I say maybe the library have pch or invalid include order that cause the problem